# plots are not displayed in Visual studio code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

When I run a python code in visual studio code IDE, the `plt.show()` does not display the plot.
Is there any way to get this working?

The code is stopped at `plt.show()` but I am not finding the display anywhere.

I am using ssh to access a remote linux system from my windows laptop.

[image]

Comment: It will create the plot in a separate window, different than Jupyter.

Comment: Thank you @TimRoberts for the response. The code got stopped at plt.show() but I cannot find the plot display anywhere. Please review the screenshot of my screen.

Comment: You didn't tell us the whole story.  Based on that window, you have an ssh connection into some other computer.  The graph is being displayed on THAT computer.  You could make this work by running an X server (like xming) and using X forwarding in your ssh connection.

Comment: Thank you @TimRoberts. Now I am able to understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`plt. show()` will open a new window and display the drawing.

If you want to display it directly in VSCode, you can use [Jupyter-notebook](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/jupyter-notebooks).

Comment: Thank you @MingJie-MSFT for the response. The issue is coming when I access the remote system (through ssh) from my laptop using vscode

Comment: Can [document](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/jupyter-notebooks#_connect-to-a-remote-jupyter-server) solve your problem?

Comment: Yes, the notebook works but visual studio code cannot display the plot when I execute .py file 
@MingJie-MSFT